# php regex to get all int or decimal from pattern

Tags: php, regex

Purpose of my code to get all take profit which has int or decimal value. writing pattern of Takeprofit will not same.

**Problem:**

1. i want $m[3][4] or $m[4][4] as 1.0870 but i got only 0870. i am getting this result when number starts from 1.xxxx. They are conflicting. I can not solve
2. TP-----1.0870 and TP=1.0870 are not detected

**My Code:**

```php
<?php
$s = 'SS 1.0140 SL 1.0670 TP1 1.0870 TP 1 1.0870 TP 2 1.0870 Takeprofit1 1.0870 Take profit 1 1.0870 TP 1.0870 TP-----1.0870 TP=1.0870 TP1=1.0870 TP Open';

$p = '#\b(TP1|TP 1|TP2|TP 2|TP3|TP 3|TAKE PROFIT 1|TAKE PROFIT 2|TAKE PROFIT 3|TAKEPROFIT 1|TAKEPROFIT 2|TAKEPROFIT 3|TAKEPROFIT\|TP)(.*?)(\bOpen\b|\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b)\b#i';

preg_match_all($p , $s , $m);
```

**Result of $m:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => TP1 1.0870
            [1] => TP 1 1.0870
            [2] => TP 2 1.0870
            [3] => Take profit 1 1.0870
            [4] => TP 1.0870
            [5] => TP1=1.0870
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => TP1
            [1] => TP 1
            [2] => TP 2
            [3] => Take profit 1
            [4] => TP 1
            [5] => TP1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  
            [1] =>  
            [2] =>  
            [3] =>  
            [4] => .
            [5] => =
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.0870
            [1] => 1.0870
            [2] => 1.0870
            [3] => 1.0870
            [4] => 0870
            [5] => 1.0870
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.0870
            [1] => 1.0870
            [2] => 1.0870
            [3] => 1.0870
            [4] => 0870
            [5] => 1.0870
        )

)
```

Comment: I'd try something like [`\b(T(?:ake ?)?[Pp](?:rofit)? *\d*)\b[ =-]+(\d[\d.,]*|[Oo]pen)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/9W7JX5/5) (updated with `open` which isn't obvious from your post)

Comment: If you would like the question to be clarified, please request it.  If you intend to provide a solution, please post an answer.  Solutions are not meant to be posted as comments. When are you extreme regex veterans (not just you, @bobble) going stop breaking Stack Exchange design?  This has been going on for waaaaaay too long and it is role modeling bad behavior to new volunteers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~\b(TAKE ?PROFIT ?(?:[1-3]|\|TP)|TP ?(?:[1-3](?!\.\d))?)\b(.*?)\b(Open|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))\b~i'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mumHSR/3)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(TAKE ?PROFIT ?(?:[1-3]|\|TP)|TP ?(?:[1-3](?!\.\d))?)` - *Group 1*: `TAKE`, an optional space, `PROFIT`, an optional space, then a digit from `1` to `3` or `|TP` substring, or `TP` with an optional space after it that is optionally followed with `1`, `2` or `3` that are not followed with `.` and a digit
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(.*?)` - *Group 2*: any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(Open|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))` - *Group 3*: `Open` or *Group 4*: 1+ digits followed with an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits
- `\b` - word boundary.

Comment: wow really nice solution. but it is not detecting properly TP 1.0870. getting only 0870. which is match 6 in link

Comment: it can be only TP without number or TP1 or TP 1 @ Wiktor

Comment: @MoinUddin So, the `1`, `2` or `3` after `TP` cannot be followed with `.`+digit. See adjusted pattern.

Comment: i am really surprised :D Thanks for helping. it works properly